# What is the exact time to live as a human before getting moksha?

Tags: scripture, moksha, time, human

Consider the following words of Indra from the Mahabharatha

> From the order of brute life one attains to the status of humanity. If
> born as human being, he is sure to take birth as a Pukkasa or a
> Chandala. Verily, one having taken birth in that sinful order of
> existence, viz., Pukkasa, one, O Matanga, has to wander in it for a
> very long time. **Passing a period of one thousand years in that order**,
> one attains next to the status of a Sudra. In the Sudra order, again,
> one has to wander for a long time. **After thirty thousand years one
> acquire the status of a Vaisya**. There, in that order, one has to pass
> a very long period. **After a time that is sixty times longer than what
> has been stated as the period of Sudra existence**, one becomes a person
> of the fighting order. In the Kshatriya order one has to pass a very
> long time. **After a time that is measured by multiplying the period
> last referred to by sixty**, one becomes born as a fallen Brahmana. In
> this order one has to wander for a long period. **After a time measured
> by multiplying the period last named by two hundred**, one becomes born
> in the race of such a Brahmana as lives by the profession of arms.
> There, in that order, one has to wander for a long period. **After a
> time measured by multiplying the period last named by three hundred**,
> one takes birth in the race of a Brahmana that is given to the
> recitation of the Gayatri and other sacred Mantras. There, in that
> order, one has to wander for a long period. **After a time measured by
> multiplying the period last named by four hundred**, one takes birth in
> the race of such a Brahmana as is conversant with the entire Vedas and
> the scriptures, There, in that order, one has to wander for **a very
> long period**. **While wandering in that status of existence, joy and
> grief, desire and aversion, vanity and evil speech, seek to enter into
> him and make a wretch of him. If he succeeds in subjugating those
> foes, he then attains a high end. If, on the other hand, those enemies
> succeed in subjugating him, he falls down from that high status like a
> person falling down on the ground from the high top of a palmyra tree.**
>
> [[Section 28, Anusasanika Parva, Anusasana Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a028.ht)

We can observe that, after taking birth as a human, there are several stages before getting moksha. The above passage gives the exact time spans for each stage except the last. And the last stage seems to be conditional compared to others. If a person **lives properly during the last stage**, then she will be promoted to moksha. But the exact time span is not given for the last stage. I summarized the information provided in the paragraph for convenience

| Stage | No.of years to live | After Calculation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pukkasa or a Chandala | 1,000 | 1000 |
| Sudra | 30,000 | 30000 |
| Vaisya | 60 * 30,000 | 1800000 |
| Kshatriya | 60 * 60 * 30,000 | 108000000 |
| fallen Brahmana | 200 * 60 * 60 * 30,000 | 21600000000 |
| profession of arms Brahmana | 300 * 200 * 60 * 60 * 30,000 | 6480000000000 |
| Mantra recitable Brahmana | 400 * 300 * 200 * 60 * 60 * 30,000 | 2592000000000000 |
| Expert Brahmana | Not given | Not given |
| **Available Total** | --- | **2598501709831000** |

Thus it takes **at least** 2598501709831000 ( read as *2 quadrillion 598 trillion 501 billion 709 million 831 thousand*) years for a human to reach moksha. It is the lower bound. It seems to me that there is **no upper bound** as there is always a chance of falling down from the last stage if the person does not live with recommended behavior. I want to know the exact time for a human to get moksha if she lives as per the scriptures. It can be obtained if there is any mention in scriptures about the time span for the last stage, which is mentioned as *very long* in the paragraph.

**What is the exact time for a human, who is living properly, to get moksha?**

---

Notes

#1: It is a general scale. Don't try to compare with people who are doing some sadhana, based on scriptures, that can lessen the time.

#2: We are considering the time span only for a human and it does not cover any non-human form. So, there is no need to mention the time spans for non-human forms in the answer.

Comment: these are still small timescales compared to eternity. anantha kalpa koti kala karma-yoga punya phala tyaga is needed for bhakti towards bhagavan.

Comment: Many many. Life times.

Comment: These seem to be somekind of averages or ideal cases. Because according to Dwaita, many souls never get moksha.

Comment: @DanielChase Oh! interesting.